# Can you unsend a gmail if you have completely deleted it even from trash section?

Tags: gmail, delete

I actually sent a gmail yesterday and after sending it, I deleted that email from my device and also from trash section, but now I want to do delete that gmail from the person who I sent it? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. _now I want to do delete that gmail from the person who I sent it?_ Are you asking in general terms, or specifically regarding the `Recall an email with Undo Send`? AS I understand it, and I may be wrong, if the former then "NO" you can't recall an email. In the case of the latter, Gmail's `Send cancellation period` is only available within a period between 5 and 30 seconds after the "send".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some email systems like a business running Microsoft exchange theoretically have a way to recall a message. In reality they almost never work.

- The person who has already read the email, will not have it deleted.
- Those who haven't read the email will get a message saying that "Rehan Sanadi" wants to recall the message X.

But if the message was send outside of the corporation to people using gmail, hotmail, AOL, or any other ISPs email system will never even be told about the recall attempt.

The only people that have the power to fully delete the message are those with admin rights to the email system at the recipients. They do this all the time if they discover a phishing attempt, or a virus in a message that got past the scanners.

The average user has no ability to delete messages from other email systems.